# How do the characters' ages fit together in Blood & Chocolate?

Tags: plot-explanation, blood-and-chocolate

In the movie *Blood & Chocolate* from 2007, the protagonist's aunt, Astrid has a son, who she mourns deeply, so I assume she's his biological mother.

But, Gabriel, the leader of the pack, is also referring to him as his son and also mourns him. Yet, he only has been with Astrid for 7 years as of the time of the movie. But said cousin is well over 7 years of age.

So who are his biological parents? Did Gabriel adopt him, or Astrid? Or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both his biological parents.

Gabriel and Astrid were together for seven years--it just wasn't the last/most recent seven years. In the movie, he takes a new mate every seven years, so presumably the timeline went like this:

1. Gabriel and Astrid are together for seven years and produce a son
2. Gabriel has some number of additional mates (I'm guessing 2-4, depending on hold old the son is supposed to be). During this time, he occasionally sleeps with Astrid.
3. Time of the movie

Comment: Oh well that makes more sense. Since we see him being somewhat close to Astrid, I thought they were the recent seven-year relationship. What you say seems to be true since Vivian has to inform her aunt about when he arrives at their house, to which Astrid reacts by making sure she looks good and preparing for him eagerly. That's a solid explanation, thanks.